# Visual Studio Code change language version to c# 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

How do I change the language version in VS Code for C# 4 to C# 6.

I'm currently experiencing the following error:

> 'Feature 'expression-bodied property' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 6 or greater.

Comment: Use .NET 4.5.2 or above as the targeting framwork

Comment: @Julian why delete? Your answer is good...

Comment: @ZoharPeled thx.  I read Visual Studio, but this is about Visual Studio *code* - oops

Comment: In visual studio you can press ctrl-enter and it's done...

Comment: @Julian you and me both :-)

Comment: @apomene how do I exactly change the targeting framework?